# Filter function by name React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-native, react-hooks

I need a function to filter by name, The data comes from my Laravel API, I wanted to make a filter on the screen to search for the account name. I am new to React.

```
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

const endpoint = "http://localhost:8000/api";
const AccountShow = () => {
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllAccounts();
  }, []);

  const getAllAccounts = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${endpoint}/accounts`);
    setAccounts(response.data);
  };

  const deleteAccount = async (id) => {
    await axios.delete(`${endpoint}/account/${id}`);
    getAllAccounts();
  };

  return (
    <div className="d-grid gap-2">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-8">
          <Form className="d-flex m-1">
            <Form.Control
              type="search"
              placeholder="Filtro"
              className="me-2"
              aria-label="Search"
            />
            <Button variant="outline-secondary">Search</Button>
          </Form>
        </div>
        <div className="col-4">
          <Link
            to="/account/create"
            className="col-11 btn btn-outline-primary m-1 "
          >
            Create
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Table hover className="">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th className="col-2" scope="col">
              Nome
            </th>
            <th className="col-2" scope="col">
              Razão Social
            </th>
            <th scope="col">Status da Conta</th>
            <th scope="col">Setor</th>
            <th scope="col">Segmento Atuacao</th>
            <th scope="col">Natureza Juridica</th>
            <th scope="col">Capital</th>
            <th scope="col">Funcionarios</th>
            <th className="text-center" scope="col">
              Ações
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {accounts.map((account) => (
            <tr key={account.id}>
              <th>{account.id}</th>
              <td>{account.nome}</td>
              <td>{account.razaoSocial}</td>
              <td>{account.statusConta}</td>
              <td>{account.setor}</td>
              <td>{account.segmentoAtuacao}</td>
              <td>{account.naturezaJuridica}</td>
              <td>{account.capital}</td>
              <td>{account.funcionarios}</td>
              <td className="text-center">
                <Link
                  to={`edit/${account.id}`}
                  className="btn btn-outline-warning"
                >
                  Editar
                </Link>
                <button
                  onClick={() => deleteAccount(account.id)}
                  className="btn btn-outline-danger m-1"
                >
                  Deletar
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AccountShow;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct way to filter.

```
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

const endpoint = "http://localhost:8000/api";
const AccountShow = () => {
  const searchQuery = useState("");
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);
  const [accountToShow, setAccountsToShow] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAccountsToShow(accounts.filter((account) => /*filter by a specific parameter here depending on what you want to filter it by; by the account.nome field?*/ account.nome.includes(searchQuery)));
  }, [accounts, searchQuery]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllAccounts();
  }, []);

  const getAllAccounts = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${endpoint}/accounts`);
    setAccounts(response.data);
  };

  const deleteAccount = async (id) => {
    await axios.delete(`${endpoint}/account/${id}`);
    getAllAccounts();
  };

  return (
    <div className="d-grid gap-2">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-8">
          <Form className="d-flex m-1">
            <Form.Control
              onChange={({target}) => setSearchQuery(target.value)}
              value={searchQuery}
              type="search"
              placeholder="Filtro"
              className="me-2"
              aria-label="Search"
            />
            <Button variant="outline-secondary">Search</Button>
          </Form>
        </div>
        <div className="col-4">
          <Link
            to="/account/create"
            className="col-11 btn btn-outline-primary m-1 "
          >
            Create
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Table hover className="">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th className="col-2" scope="col">
              Nome
            </th>
            <th className="col-2" scope="col">
              Razão Social
            </th>
            <th scope="col">Status da Conta</th>
            <th scope="col">Setor</th>
            <th scope="col">Segmento Atuacao</th>
            <th scope="col">Natureza Juridica</th>
            <th scope="col">Capital</th>
            <th scope="col">Funcionarios</th>
            <th className="text-center" scope="col">
              Ações
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {accountsToShow.map((account) => (
            <tr key={account.id}>
              <th>{account.id}</th>
              <td>{account.nome}</td>
              <td>{account.razaoSocial}</td>
              <td>{account.statusConta}</td>
              <td>{account.setor}</td>
              <td>{account.segmentoAtuacao}</td>
              <td>{account.naturezaJuridica}</td>
              <td>{account.capital}</td>
              <td>{account.funcionarios}</td>
              <td className="text-center">
                <Link
                  to={`edit/${account.id}`}
                  className="btn btn-outline-warning"
                >
                  Editar
                </Link>
                <button
                  onClick={() => deleteAccount(account.id)}
                  className="btn btn-outline-danger m-1"
                >
                  Deletar
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AccountShow;
```

Comment: When I put your code, it gives me the following error:
react-dom.development.js:12056 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to read null properties (reading 'includes')

Comment: @Coimbra, what is your account's object type? Does it contain a field "nome"?

Answer (score -1):

You can filter data using

> useMemo()

```
const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);
const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

const filterData = useMemo(() => {
        if (accounts && accounts?.length > 0) {
            return accounts.filter(item =>
                item?.name
                    .toLocaleLowerCase('en')
                    .includes(query.trim().toLocaleLowerCase('en')),
            );
        }
    }, [accounts, query]);
```

you can set query using textbox change event

Comment: What is the purpose of using the useMemo hook? It doesn't make sense to use it here.

useMemo is used to prevent unecessary rerendering. It makes more sense to use useEffect here